# How to detect lines in an image using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking for a way to detect lines in an image using Python with the OpenCV library. What OpenCV functions should I use to find and determine the positions of lines in the image? Specifically, how can I use image processing techniques to identify the most prominent lines in a given image?

Could you provide an example Python code along with explanations?

Thank you.
this code is simple

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import traceback
import logging
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import time

logging.basicConfig(filename='error_log.txt', level=logging.ERROR)


class ImageProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process_image(self, image_path):
        try:
            start_time = time.time()

            original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

            if original_image is None:
                raise Exception("Dosya yüklenemedi. Dosya yolunu kontrol edin.")

            marked_image = self.process_and_measure(original_image)

            cv2.imshow("Marked Image", marked_image)

            end_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time) * 1000
            print(f"İşleme Süresi: {elapsed_time:.2f} ms")

            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'HATA: {str(e)}')
            traceback.print_exc()

    def process_and_measure(self, original_image):
        equalized_image = cv2.equalizeHist(original_image)

        clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
        processed_image = clahe.apply(equalized_image)

        _, thresholded = cv2.threshold(processed_image, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        if contours:
            largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

            m = cv2.moments(largest_contour)

            average_x = int(m["m10"] / m["m00"])
            center_x = original_image.shape[1] // 2
            distance_from_center = average_x - center_x

            marked_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            cv2.line(marked_image, (center_x, 0), (center_x, original_image.shape[0]), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.line(marked_image, (average_x, 0), (average_x, original_image.shape[0]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            cv2.putText(marked_image, f"{distance_from_center} px", (center_x + 10, original_image.shape[0] // 2), font,
                        0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            return marked_image

        else:
            return cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


class AdvancedInterface:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Gelişmiş Arayüz")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=800, height=600, bg="white")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

        self.btn_select_image = tk.Button(master, text="Resim Seç", command=self.select_image)
        self.btn_select_image.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.btn_select_video = tk.Button(master, text="Video Seç", command=self.select_video)
        self.btn_select_video.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.btn_capture_image = tk.Button(master, text="Kamera Görüntüsü", command=self.capture_image)
        self.btn_capture_image.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.btn_up = tk.Button(master, text="↑", command=self.move_up, width=5, height=2)
        self.btn_up.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.btn_down = tk.Button(master, text="↓", command=self.move_down, width=5, height=2)
        self.btn_down.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.btn_left = tk.Button(master, text="←", command=self.move_left, width=5, height=2)
        self.btn_left.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.btn_right = tk.Button(master, text="→", command=self.move_right, width=5, height=2)
        self.btn_right.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.btn_exit = tk.Button(master, text="Programı Kapat", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.btn_exit.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.image_processor = ImageProcessor()

    def select_image(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Resim Seç", filetypes=[("PNG files", "*.png")])
        if file_path:
            print("Seçilen Resim:", file_path)
            self.image_processor.process_image(file_path)

    def select_video(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Video Seç", filetypes=[("Video Files", "*.mp4")])
        if file_path:
            print("Seçilen Video:", file_path)

    def capture_image(self):
        print("Kamera Görüntüsü Alındı")

    def move_up(self):
        print("Yukarı Hareket")

    def move_down(self):
        print("Aşağı Hareket")

    def move_left(self):
        print("Sol Hareket")

    def move_right(self):
        print("Sağ Hareket")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AdvancedInterface(root)
    root.mainloop()`
```

Comment: Please show the input image. Have you tried HoughLines?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to determine the position / likelihood of a sub-image (in this case, a line) appearing within a given image, one could make use of the template matching functions within OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Here's a sample of code from a project of mine:

```
def findImage(img1:Image, img2:Image):
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img1.data, img2.data, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    return max_val
```

In this case, I had used a custom implementation of a `Image` class, but all you really need to do to modify for your use case is to pass the "data" of the image (this is typically the `np.array` version of the photo/live video) in the `cv2.matchTemplate` function. If you are concerned with the likelihood of a match, you can use any of the `_NORMED` algorithms, as this will normalize scores between 0 and 1.

In the sample above, I have passed two images into the matchTemplate, and then used `cv2.minMaxLoc(res)` to retrieve the minimum and maximum scores for that sub image match, as well as the min and max locations of where the sub-image was found. This was useful for my use-case as I only needed the highest likelihood score, but if there exist multiple lines within one image, you might need to manually explore the `res` output, as this is a set of data representing how good of a match the sub-image is at all given coordinates in the parent image.

(Also, I'm assuming here that the lines you're looking for are consistent, and that it would be trivial to crop out a sample of what they look like and use that as the source `img1` data versus the photo which acts as the template `img2` data)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no coding knowledge. I added the examples you provided to my code with the help of ChatGPT, but there was no difference. Additionally, I tried to implement template matching, but this time my program broke. Thank you very much